# how to restrict access to the route

Tags: reactjs, forms, redirect, react-router, submit

i have in my App.js

```
render() {
    return (
        <Router history={customHistory}>
            <div>
                    <Header/>
                    <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage}/>
                    <Route exact path="/test" component={ThankYou} />
                    <Route path="*" component={NotFound} status={404}/>
                    </Switch>
                    <Footer/>                        
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
}
```

this routs, and i have contact form [added code to codpen for convenience](https://codepen.io/annbin/pen/QWLroYv)

How to make sure that the component on the route

`<Route exact path = "/test" component = {Test} />`

could only go after success submit the form, and if you try to do it at another time, then redirect to 404

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be which is generic would be to create `PrivateRoute`.

Based on the state - `formSubmitted`, we can redirect to `notFound` or 404 route.

```
class ProtectedRoute extends Component {
  render() {
    const { component: Component, ...props } = this.props

    return (
      <Route 
        {...props} 
        render={props => (
          this.state.formSubmitted ?
            <Component {...props} /> :
            <Redirect to='/notFound' />
        )}
      />
    )
  }
}

class AllRoutes extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
        <ProtectedRoute path='/test' component={ThankYou} />
        <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I understood correctly, I create the ProtectedRoute class in the folder with app.js, (in it my routes), in it I write what you wrote and import in app.js, after which I write a new ProtectedRoute in it?

Comment: I just get an error in this way
`The above error occurred in the <ProtectedRoute>`